# Model with nested attribute creation changes association type attribute between before_validation and before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I have a model, `Guest` which takes nested attributes for `Numberplate`.

`Guest` adopts STI (single table inheritance) and inherits from `Person`. To prevent the need for extra queries or joining to another table I save the person type in a field called `person_type` in the `Numberplate` table. That way, I know which Numberplates are owned by Guests without the need of joining with the persons table.

Due to this setup, I need to manually set the correct `person_type` on a `Numberplate` (there is another person type). I implemented this as a `before_validation` callback on the `Numberplate` model:

```
before_validation do
    self.person_type = self.person.type
end
```

The actual implementation is a bit more generic but it boils down to this.
Now I would create a `Guest` and `Numberplate` in one call in the console this all works as expected:

`Numberplate.new({person: Guest.new({company: Company.first}), plate: 'EFEF98'})`

The `person_type` on the `Numberplate` instance is correctly set to `"Guest"`.

The issue arises when I have an API endpoint that allows nested attributes to create the `Guest` and `Numberplate` in one request. The strange thing is that the `person_type` gets stored as `"Person'` and not `"Guest"` as expected. I debugged a bit and the `person_type` gets set correctly in the `before_validation` callback but between that callback and the `before_save` callback the `person_type` is suddenly changed to `"Person"`.
I tried to override the `person_type` setter and log when it gets set. The strange thing is that the setter is not called between the 2 ActiveRecord callbacks.

I'm a bit flabbergasted as to how this behavior is introduced, and whether this is a bug in the Rails core somewhere or I'm not accounting for something. My current workaround is to also set the `person_type` in an additional `before_save` callback but this doesn't feel like an optimal solution.

Relevant models:

```
class Guest < Person
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :numberplates
end

class Numberplate < ApplicationRecord
    before_validation do
        self.person_type = self.person.type
    end

    after_validation do
        # person_type is correctly set to "Guest"
        puts self.inspect
    end

    before_create do
        # person_type is now suddenly set to "Person"
        puts self.inspect
    end
end
```

Comment: Try an [association callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Association+callbacks) instead.

Comment: @max just tried, displays same behavior

Comment: Something is setting the person_type column to Person, even without any custom code on my side. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

In the `Person` class I had this:

```
has_many :numberplates, as: :person, inverse_of: :person
```

The `as: :person` part should not be there and introduced this behavior. It was there due to an earlier migration from polymorphism to STI and was thus a forgotten leftover. Once I removed this everything worked as expected.